# Very Large Values Predicted for Linear Regression with One Hot Encoding

Tags: regression, categorical-data, python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to run a linear regression in python to determine house prices given many features.  Some of these are numeric and some are non-numeric.  I'm attempting to do one hot encoding for the non-numeric columns and attach the new, numeric, columns to the old dataframe and drop the non-numeric columns.  This is done on both the training data and test data.

I then took the intersection of the two columns features (since I had some encodings that were only located in the testing data).  Afterwards, it goes into  a linear regression. The code is the following:

```
non_numeric = list(set(list(train)) - set(list(train._get_numeric_data())))
train = pandas.concat([train, pandas.get_dummies(train[non_numeric])], axis=1)
train.drop(non_numeric, axis=1, inplace=True)

train = train._get_numeric_data()
train.fillna(0, inplace = True)

non_numeric = list(set(list(test)) - set(list(test._get_numeric_data())))
test = pandas.concat([test, pandas.get_dummies(test[non_numeric])], axis=1)
test.drop(non_numeric, axis=1, inplace=True)

test = test._get_numeric_data()
test.fillna(0, inplace = True)

feature_columns = list(set(train) & set(test))
#feature_columns.remove('SalePrice')
X = train[feature_columns]
y = train['SalePrice']

lm = LinearRegression()
lm.fit(X, y)

import numpy
predictions = numpy.absolute(lm.predict(test).round(decimals = 2))
```

The issue that I'm having is that I get these absurdly high Sale Prices as output, somewhere in the hundreds of millions of dollars (sometimes even in the trillions).  Before I tried one hot encoding I got reasonable numbers in the hundreds of thousands of dollars.  I'm having trouble figuring out what changed.  I posted this on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44712521/very-large-values-predicted-for-linear-regression) and got a response suggesting that it might be a collinearity issue, but I tried setting `fit_intercept` parameter of `LinearRegression` to False as well as setting `drop_first` parameter of `get_dummies` to True.

Also, if there is a better way to do this I'd be eager to hear about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is at least one point that seems very suspicious.

Consider the lines

```
train = pandas.concat([train, pandas.get_dummies(train[non_numeric])], axis=1)
```

and

```
test = pandas.concat([test, pandas.get_dummies(test[non_numeric])], axis=1)
```

Specifically, the parts

```
pandas.get_dummies(train[non_numeric])
```

and

```
pandas.get_dummies(test[non_numeric])
```

Note that this depends on the *values* of the matrices. There is no reason implying that the generated columns *must* be the same, and so it's hard to guess the effect on the prediction of the test data.

In general, when performing `get_dummies`, it is better to do it before train/test splits (including cross-validation). This is an unsupervised transformation anyway, so it is not "peeking".

Comment: That worked, thanks.  Do you have any idea why `feature_columns = list(set(train) & set(test))` didn't take care of this problem?

Comment: @David IIUC, it is because the line you mentioned is determined by the *headers* of the DataFrame, whereas the code that follows after it, manipulates things based on the *content* of the DataFrame. Hence, even if the headers are the same for the train and test DataFrames, the resulting columns may not be identical.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  I thought that the headers would be consistent with the data in them since they contain the header label and the categorical label, but I guess not.

Answer (score 0):

I think your linear regression has a collinearity issue.  When you call `pd.get_dummies`, you get a dummy column for *every* level of the categorical variable

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 1], 'b': [1, 3, 1], 'c': ['a', 'b', 'a']})

In [3]: pd.get_dummies(df)
Out[13]:
   a  b  c_a  c_b
0  1  1    1    0
1  2  3    0    1
2  1  1    1    0
```

If you then plug this directly into a linear regression, the dummy columns for each categorical variable will be co-linear.  This means your regression fitting algorithm will not converge, and your coefficients will not be unstable, and border on meaningless.

I would recommend using [patsy](https://patsy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to construct design matrices for regression in python.  It will take care of co-linearity issues for you.